# JSON Post works fine as plain text, when using variable issue

Tags: node.js, function

Just playing around when I notice that when I assign the variables:

```
var username = someString.substr(0, index); 
var password = someString.substr(index + 1);
```

(Note: All the data is correct and what i want)

And then i try and use them while posting JSON:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    "ctype": "Username",
    "cvalue": username,
    "password": password
}),
```

It does not recognise or can read the variables correctly as I get incorrect sign in, However when I use:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    "ctype": "Username",
    "cvalue": "Usernamehere",
    "password": "passwordhere"
}),
```

It works perfectly fine, sorry if this is obvious. New to Node.js

UPDATE, WITH MORE CODE:

```
request("server.com", function (err, response, body) {
    if (body) 


    var someString = body;
    var index = someString.indexOf(":");  // Gets the first index where a space occours
    var username = someString.substr(0, index);
    var password = someString.substr(index);

    console.log("Username:" + username + " Password:" + password);
```

Comment: When you `console.log(someString)`, what us the output? Is it exactly "Usernamehere:passwordhere" ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think the issue will not be related to NodeJs or JSON post it is about how you are using `substr`. The second argument is this function is not for the end index, it’s for the amount of characters. So your password is skipping the character at "index".

Try

```
var username = someString.substr(0, index);
var password = someString.substr(index);
```

Comment: Thank you, ill take a look sir. Update: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please update your question with a bit more of your code. Especially the string `someString`